# POST http://localhost:8000/index/bots 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am still new in laravel and i got this message error when I am insert using query builder

> POST http://localhost:8000/index/bots 500 (Internal Server Error)

and this is in controller

```
$countries = array("Australia","Japan","Mexico","United States","Italia","Greece","France","Hungary","Estados Unidos","Deutschland","United Kingdom");
            $country = $countries[rand(1,count($countries) - 1)];
            $deviceId = "";
              DB::table('players', 'stats')->insert(array(
                'dealerId' => '1',
                'username' =>  request('botName'),
                'player' => request('botName'),
                'banned' => '0',
                'approve' => '1',
                'winpot' => '100000',
                'deviceId' => '.$deviceId.',
                'myTime' => '0',
                'country' => '.$country.',
                'bot' => '1'
));
```

Comment: what error you got? and `deviceId ` and `$country` no need of `.` (dots) or single quoates. just assign it directly. and try to start the rand from 0 as "Australia" wont be pickedup. according to your logic.

Comment: Not sure what caused the issue, but there is another problem in your code: `'country' => '.$country.',` should be `'country' => $country,`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a 500 Internal Server means something went wrong on the server side. There are likely two causes for this in your situation:

1. PHP encountered a syntax error.
2. A problem exists between your PHP server and your database.

Check your [PHP Server logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127884/228489) for more information.

Comment: please check your database. there can  be some fields missing.